# Three.js / WebGL - Sphere - scene visible countries / colors

Tags: javascript, three.js

I had implemented a globe similar to [this one](https://s3.amazonaws.com/SocialHarvest/aggregate.html) 
But while trying to fetch the countries visible to the scene in Three.js when the globe is in a stationary position am stuck in a issue. I can retrieve the country color code when I mouse over / click on a specific country using **readPixels** and get the appropriate color code of the pixel as shown below

```js
var gl = renderer.context;
var mx = ( mouseX + renderer.context.canvas.width/2 );//(mouseX + renderer.context.canvas.width/2) * 0.25;
var my = ( -mouseY + renderer.context.canvas.height/2 );//(-mouseY + renderer.context.canvas.height/2) * 0.25;
mx = Math.floor( mx );
my = Math.floor( my );
var buf = new Uint8Array( 4 );       
gl.readPixels( mx, my, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf );
```

But when the globe stopped rotating then I need to get the list of user viewable countries from the scene, I tried to use Raycaster to get the mesh and scan through all the pixels and get the country code but seems to be a performance hit for us

Appreciate if someone can provide their views

Answer (score 1):

You can render the scene to a texture (even with different shaders/uniforms). There are examples on the official site, like this: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_rtt.html

For instance you could have a scene where the **texture of the globe is country coded**, and when the user clicks, you render that scene into a texture and read single pixel from that texture.

Be careful, when rendering to textures, you sometimes have to force update your textures by setting `needsUpdate` to `true`.

Hope I helped.